# Como acessar propriedade com # em um arquivo JSON com JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Olá, 
estou usando a api do Last.fm e estou com dificuldade em acessar o #text que se encontra dentro do array image.

Link dos dados ->
[JSON](http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=tag.gettoptracks&tag=edm&limit=10&api_key=0e5b7fa47c1b474b4448c2c7030e6e41&format=json)

Eu tento:

```
console.log(values.track[index].image[index].#text);
```

Mas não funciona. Como posso resolver?

Answer (score 1):

É só usar `values.track[index].image[index]['#text']`